# shell cant capture output in file using > and >>

Tags: android, linux, shell

I know about `>` and `>>`, but cant capture output for below code.
I have 3 files, i want to open file one by one using `CAT`.
I would search for a specific string/message using `GREP`, if Found `PASS` else `FAIL`.
Code is working but can not get a output in file.

```
XXXXXXXXXX/XXX/XXX/postprocessing$ ls
demo.txt  tag.txt  tc1_adblog.txt  tc2_adblog.txt  tc3_adblog.txt


XXXXXXXXXX/XXX/XXX/postprocessing$ cat tc1_adblog.txt | grep  'ActivityRecord{4306a670 u0 com.example.android.notepad/.NotesList t9}' && echo "Test case 1: Pass" || echo "Test case 1: FAIL" >> result.txt
I/Timeline( 1002): Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{4306a670 u0 com.example.android.notepad/.NotesList t9} time:12020671
Test case 1: Pass


XXXXXXXXXX/XXX/XXX/postprocessing$ ls
demo.txt  tag.txt  tc1_adblog.txt  tc2_adblog.txt  tc3_adblog.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`>> result.txt` is only being applied to `echo` after `||`. You need to group the whole command like this:

```
s='ActivityRecord{4306a670 u0 com.example.android.notepad/.NotesList t9}'
{ grep -qF "$s" tc1_adblog.txt && echo "Test case 1: Pass" || echo "Test case 1: FAIL"; } >> result.txt
```

- Use `grep -F` to match fixed strings
- Use `grep -q` to avoid `grep`'s output
- Avoid useless `cat`

Answer (score 0):

```
&& echo "Pass" >> result.txt || echo "Fail" >> result.txt

(grep "string" && echo "Pass" || echo "Fail") >> result.txt
```